# Library to encode (no decoding) QR code

Tags: android, qr-code

I know about zxing and I know how to use it as a jar, so I don't have to use the intent approach. But...:

1. Sean Owen, the developer behind the zxing apparently [doesn't really like people embedding it in their apps](http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/) and would prefer them to use Intent apporach which really kills user experience in my opinion.
2. I only need the encoding part. Noobishly saying: I want to have some data changed for a QR code. No need for scanning, decoding, etc.
3. It nearly doubles the size of my application, but that is the least important problem.

I googled for long, but zxing seems to be by far the most popular solution as I found nothing else. Do you know some other library or just some ready to use algorithms? I wouldn't like to re-invent the wheel...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the library provided here:
http://www.swetake.com/qr/index-e.html
The last link will take your to a Japanese site where you can download the Java library. It's old but it works.

Comment: Ages later, still going strong

Answer (score 1):

An option, if you always have internet, is to use Google's API for generating QR codes.
http://createqrcode.appspot.com/

An Example (returns a png image) : http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x300&chl=MESSAGE&chld=H|0